# Block table row while adding rows gets added on every row

Tags: javascript, html, join

I made a table which gets rows added to it by using a slide..
Seemed to work fine untill I tried to add a field on top as a blcoked row. It somehow gets added on every row... I tried adding it in differnt ways but cant seem to get it to work, do you see why? here is my code i use the join to make it work:

[image: Picutre of what i mean]

```
    <table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
            <th scope="col">Gewicht</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
            <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
$('#myRange').on('change', function(event){
    var rowNum = $('#myRange').val();
    var resultHtml = '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        resultHtml += [
            "            <tr>" ,
            "                <th scope=\"col\"></th>" ,
            "                <th scope=\"col\">Hoeveelheid</th>",
            "                <th scope=\"col\">Gewicht</th>",
            "            </tr>",



                "<tr>",
                "<td>",
                (i+1),
                "</td>",
                '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
                '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
                '</tr>'].join("\n");
    }
    $('#resultTable').html(resultHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heading row shouldn't be inside the loop.

```js
$('#myRange').on('change', function(event) {
  var rowNum = $('#myRange').val();
  var resultHtml = [
    "            <tr>",
    "                <th scope=\"col\"></th>",
    "                <th scope=\"col\">Hoeveelheid</th>",
    "                <th scope=\"col\">Gewicht</th>",
    "            </tr>"
  ].join("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
    resultHtml += [
      "<tr>",
      "<td>",
      (i + 1),
      "</td>",
      '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
      '<td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>',
      '</tr>'
    ].join("\n");
  }
  $('#resultTable').html(resultHtml);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const setup = () => {
    const myRange = document.querySelector('#myRange');
    myRange.addEventListener('click', changeEvent);
    myRange.addEventListener('change', changeEvent);

    //Update on load
    const resultTable = document.querySelector('#resultTable');
    updateTable(resultTable, myRange);

};
const changeEvent = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const resultTable = document.querySelector('#resultTable');
    updateTable(resultTable, target);
};
const updateTable = (target, slider) => {
    const tbody = target.querySelector('tbody');
    const existingRows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');

    let requestedRowsNum = parseInt(slider.value, 10);
    let currentRowNum = existingRows.length;
    let adjustRowNum = requestedRowsNum - currentRowNum;
    let amount = Math.abs(adjustRowNum);

    if(adjustRowNum > 0) insertRows(tbody, amount);
    else if(adjustRowNum < 0) deleteRows(tbody, amount);
}
const deleteRows = (tbody, amount) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        tbody.querySelector('tr:last-child').remove();
};
const insertRows = (tbody, amount) => {
    let nextRowNumber = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
    for(let i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
        insertRowHTML(tbody, nextRowNumber + i);
};
const insertRowHTML = (target, rowNumber) => target.appendChild(createRowHTML(rowNumber));
const createRowHTML = (rowNumber) => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let cel1 = document.createElement('td');
    cel1.textContent = rowNumber;
    let cel2 = createCellWithInput();
    let cel3 = createCellWithInput();

    tr.appendChild(cel1);
    tr.appendChild(cel2);
    tr.appendChild(cel3);

    return tr;

};
const createCellWithInput = () => {
    const cell = document.createElement('td');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.placeholder = 'text goes here...';
    cell.appendChild(input);

    return cell;
};


//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl-BE">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tableRowCreationSlider</title>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="myRange" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="3" class="slider-color" id="id1">
<table id="resultTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Hoeveelheid</th>
        <th scope="col">Gewicht</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
        <td><input type="name" placeholder="text goes here..."></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```